# Getting tomcat 404 error when accessing artifactory docker

Tags: docker-compose, artifactory, tomcat8, dock

I created an instance of Artifactoy in docker. I mapped its 8081 port to local 3007 port:

```
   ports:
      - "3007:8081"
```

These are done on a remote server (the docker is running on a remote server on the company network)
When accessing it using http://server-domain-name:3007, i get the following error:

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message /ui/

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/8.5.51
```

but if i run `curl http://server-domain-name:3007`, i get the following which shows that Artifactory is running:

```
<!--
  ~ Artifactory is a binaries repository manager.
  ~ Copyright (C) 2018 JFrog Ltd.
  ~
  ~ Artifactory is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
  ~ it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License as published by
  ~ the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
  ~ (at your option) any later version.
  ~
  ~ Artifactory is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  ~ but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  ~ MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
  ~ GNU Affero General Public License for more details.
  ~
  ~ You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License
  ~ along with Artifactory.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
  -->
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/artifactory">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I suspect it's something related to artifactory proxy settings, but not sure!
Any idea why I get this error and can not access it??

These are the tomcat logs within the docker container:

```
/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/log/tomcat# cat tomcat-catalina-2020-03-24.log 

24-Mar-2020 10:57:42.185 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
24-Mar-2020 10:57:42.200 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
24-Mar-2020 10:57:42.208 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8040"]
24-Mar-2020 10:57:42.209 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
24-Mar-2020 10:57:42.214 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
24-Mar-2020 10:57:42.214 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.51
24-Mar-2020 10:57:42.233 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/access.xml]
24-Mar-2020 10:57:42.233 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/artifactory.xml]
24-Mar-2020 10:57:42.252 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor A docBase [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/artifactory.war] inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored
24-Mar-2020 10:57:42.252 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor A docBase [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access.war] inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored
24-Mar-2020 10:57:50.670 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/artifactory.xml] has finished in [8,436] ms
24-Mar-2020 10:57:52.693 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/access.xml] has finished in [10,460] ms
24-Mar-2020 10:57:52.694 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
24-Mar-2020 10:57:52.705 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [11] ms
24-Mar-2020 10:57:52.708 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
24-Mar-2020 10:57:52.724 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8040"]
24-Mar-2020 12:20:14.606 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
24-Mar-2020 12:20:14.606 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
24-Mar-2020 12:20:14.612 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8040"]
24-Mar-2020 12:20:14.617 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
24-Mar-2020 12:20:19.751 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
24-Mar-2020 12:20:19.751 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8040"]
24-Mar-2020 12:20:19.752 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
24-Mar-2020 12:20:19.753 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8040"]
24-Mar-2020 12:20:26.296 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
24-Mar-2020 12:20:26.312 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
24-Mar-2020 12:20:26.320 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8040"]
24-Mar-2020 12:20:26.321 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
24-Mar-2020 12:20:26.326 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
24-Mar-2020 12:20:26.326 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.51
24-Mar-2020 12:20:26.339 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/access.xml]
24-Mar-2020 12:20:26.339 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/artifactory.xml]
24-Mar-2020 12:20:26.363 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor A docBase [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access.war] inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored
24-Mar-2020 12:20:26.363 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor A docBase [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/artifactory.war] inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored
24-Mar-2020 12:20:28.904 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/artifactory.xml] has finished in [2,564] ms
24-Mar-2020 12:20:35.030 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/access.xml] has finished in [8,691] ms
24-Mar-2020 12:20:35.031 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
24-Mar-2020 12:20:35.048 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [17] ms
24-Mar-2020 12:20:35.050 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
24-Mar-2020 12:20:35.060 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8040"]
```

```
/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/log/tomcat# cat tomcat-localhost-2020-03-24.log
24-Mar-2020 10:57:42.907 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
24-Mar-2020 10:57:45.680 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
24-Mar-2020 12:20:14.651 INFO [localhost-startStop-3] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
24-Mar-2020 12:20:26.965 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
24-Mar-2020 12:20:29.632 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
```

**Update:**
If I ssh into the docker container and run

`curl --head http://localhost:8081/artifactory/webapp/#/login`

I get this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Artifactory/7.3.2
X-Artifactory-Id: 7c88d7b6c0e91efc:e615a11:17111dedc15:-8000
X-Artifactory-Node-Id: 2dd09e552f22
Cache-Control: no-store,max-age=0
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: W/"2239-1584804418000"
Last-Modified: Sat, 21 Mar 2020 15:26:58 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 2239
Date: Wed, 25 Mar 2020 13:50:46 GMT
```

it looks like artifactory is working ok but not accessible when port 8081 is mapped to 3007 external port.
Can this be related to Apache Tomcat config inside the docker container?

Comment: it seems that the error is coming from "Apache Tomcat/8.5.51"  or Artifactoy if it uses Apache. make sure that you test in a private window and try to provide a path the URL

Comment: if i access it (http://server-domain-name:3007) in a browser, it redirects to http://server-domain-name:3007/ui and i get Apache Tomcat 404 Error

Comment: what is the output of this command `curl --head http://server-domain-name:3007 `

Comment: It is 

```HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: W/"878-1584802560000"
Last-Modified: Sat, 21 Mar 2020 14:56:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 878
Date: Wed, 25 Mar 2020 11:53:08 GMT```

Comment: did you try browse `http://server-domain-name:3007` in a different browser or a private window

Comment: yes, but it does not work!

Comment: Hi @user3426603, I have the same problem right now. Did you find a solution to your problem?